# WCF data services - custom provider examples

Tags: wcf, wcf-data-services, odata

I'm trying to expose my existing server application with a new WCF data service.
I cannot use EF, because it means that I'll have to rewrite the whole thing....

Unfortunatelly all of the examples I find in the web about WCF data services and OData, either involve EF, or are very basic and use mock data. I'm looking for a more real life use of WCF data services with custom provider or the toolkit, that will show me :

1. Returning complex types (or wrapping real entities with header entities), to expose state_id or other attributes that are not  part of my DB tables yet need to pass them to the client on every request.
2. Defining Navigation properties to allow me to supply additional linked data such as:
   http://services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/Customers('ALFKI')?$expand=Orders

   elaborate more about difference between linking one-to-many - compared to many-to-many